# Ordered set has a maximum and every subset has infimum $\implies$ every subset has supremum

Tags: order-theory, supremum-and-infimum, lattice-orders

> Let $M$ be an ordered set such that
>
> $a)$ $M$ has a maximum element
>
> $b)$ Every (non-empty) subset of $M$ has an infimun.
>
> Prove that every non-empty subset of $M$ also has a supremum.

I tried fixing a subset $A$ and considering its set of majorants, which is non-empty (since it contains $\sup M$), so must have an infimum $a'$. What is left to prove is that $a'$ belongs to this set, but I cannnot follow this up. Any hints are appreciated.

Source (Romanian book): Ion D. Ion, R. Nicolae, "Algebra", Editura Didactica si Pedagogica, Bucharest, $1981$ - problem $9$, page $22$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call $U(X)$ the set of upper bounds of $X$ and $L(X)$ the set of lower bounds of $X$. It is generally true that $L(U(X))\supseteq X$. By definition, $\inf X=\max L(X)$, and therefore $\inf U(A)=\max L(U(A))$. Since $L(U(A))\supseteq A$, we have that $\inf U(A)$ is larger than all the elements of $A$, and therefore $\inf U(A)\in U(A)$.

Comment: That's not fair (joking). Very nice idea. Thank you!